# Update Backbone.Model after Backbone.sync

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I try to send requests with `Backbone.sync`:

```
...
async createModel(model) {
  await Backbone.sync('create'/*or 'update' or 'delete'*/, model); 
  console.log(model.toJSON());
  model.fetch(); // i don't want to do this
}
...
```

After `.sync('...')` server responses with some data, but that data is not the same as `model.toJSON()`, so I need extra `.fetch()` method to correctly update my model.

Why it happens? How can I update my model right after `.sync()` without extra `.fetch()`? `{wait: true}` option doesn't help.

Comment: I found workaround: `model.set(await Backbone.sync('create', model))`

Comment: You should make your server return the same resource on any http method, not just GET

Answer (score 0):

Based off the comments it looks like you solved the issue already. However, I'm not entirely convinced you're going to get the exact behavior that your hoping for from that solution.

If you had wanted to just use sync I think you could have solved your issue a couple of other ways. According the the [Backbone documentation, Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) uses jquery.ajax and returns a jqXHR object, not the actual response data from the call. Not to mention the response data still isn't going to be formatted as a Backbone.Model. However, you can simply tack on a .done and .fail like you would with an ajax request and do your `model.set()` there.

```
...
async createModel(model) {
    await Backbone.sync('create'/*or 'update' or 'delete'*/, model)
        .done(function(data) {
            var newModel = new Model(data);
            [MODEL LOCATION].set(newModel);
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data.status);
        }); 
}
...
```

However, the other way that you could have done this exact same thing is that it looks like the [Backbone.sync function](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) takes a 3rd parameter [options] and once again based off the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) it looks like the options that it takes are success and error callbacks. So, if you use that pattern it would look like this:

```
...
async createModel(model) {
    await Backbone.sync(
        'create', //or 'update' or 'delete' 
        model,
        {
            success: function(data) {
                var newModel = new Model(data);
                [MODEL LOCATION].set(newModel);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data.status);
            }
        }
    ); 
}
...
```

In all cases the data parameter is the response data that comes back from the REST call.

Anyways, hope this helps in the future.